# Change requests timeout in Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, gunicorn

How to change Python application requests timeout in Heroku?

I tried changing in Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn -w 3 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app --timeout 600
```

but it does not work. I am using a FastAPI application.

Comment: Are you sure it's your app timing out? Depending on the length it's possible it's Heroku's router - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout